# Understand and explain the recommendations

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to use recommenderlab to build a UBCF and produce recommendations. The process is ok and the predictions seems to make sense. What I need is to explain to my peers (commercial and marketing) why I'm recommending those item to those users.

My code is:

```
library(recommenderlab) 
data(Jester5k) 

r <- sample(Jester5k, 1000)

rec_ub <- Recommender(r[1:100],method="UBCF", param=list(normalize = "Z-score",method="Cosine", nn=3,minRating=1))
recom_ub <- predict(rec_ub, Jester5k[1001:1002], n=20, type="ratings")

my.df<-as(recom_ub,"matrix")
rownames(my.df)<- rownames(Jester5k[1001:1002])

my.result<-melt(my.df, id = 1)
names(my.result)<-c("user","item","value")
my.result<-my.result[order(my.result$user,-my.result$value),]
my.result<-subset(my.result,value>0)
```

I need to know, for example, why the item j76 is being recommended to user u11691, i.e, which users are actually the neighbors (used by the recommender) of that user.

Answer (score 0):

UBCF is based on the similar users in neighbourhood of active users
Try looking at similarity function to see the most similar users (nn=20).
    similarity(r, method = "cosine",which="user")